# AWS js aws-sdk route53Domains.listDomains() returns "UnknownError: Bad Gateway"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-js

I am using the js npm library aws-sdk to query AWS objects.

From within the same script it is able to retrieve ec2 instance details using ec2.describeInstances, but when it executes `route53Domains.listDomains()` every time I get :

> UnknownError: Bad Gateway

I am using the ec2 instance authentication from the ec2 instance where this script is executing so I don't set any api keys.

Without the proxy configured no calls work at all.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const proxy = require('proxy-agent')
const Logger = require('logplease')

const logOptions = {
  useColors: false // Disable colors
}

const myLogger = Logger.create('testAws', logOptions)
Logger.setLogLevel('DEBUG')

AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: { agent: proxy('http://my.proxy.here:8080') },
  region: 'ap-southeast-2', // ec2 client needs this
  logger: myLogger
})

myLogger.log('testAws Starting')

myLogger.log('About to create ec2 client')
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2()
myLogger.log('ec2 client created')

myLogger.log('About to create route53Domainsclient')
const route53Domains = new AWS.Route53Domains()
myLogger.log('route53Domainsclient created')

function listDomains() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      myLogger.log('About to listDomains')
      const rsp = await route53Domains.listDomains({}).promise()
      myLogger.log(`Domains listed: ${JSON.stringify(rsp, null, 2)}`)
      resolve()
    } catch (err) {
      myLogger.error(`Error listDomains: ${err}`)
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}
function describeInstances() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      myLogger.log('About to describeInstances')
      const params = {}
      const response = await ec2.describeInstances(params).promise()
      myLogger.log(`Successfully describeInstances: output: ${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}`)
      resolve()
    } catch (err) {
      myLogger.error(`Error describeInstances: ${err}`)
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}

async function doInstanceOps() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    try {
      await describeInstances()
    } catch (err) {
      myLogger.log('error in describeInstances()')
    }
    myLogger.log('doInstanceOps complete')
    resolve()
  })
}

async function doRoute53Ops() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    try {
      await listDomains()
    } catch (err) {
      myLogger.error('error in doRoute53Ops()')
    }
    myLogger.log('doRoute53Ops complete')
    resolve()
  })
}

async function doEverything() {
  myLogger.log('doEverything Starting')

  await doInstanceOps()
  await doRoute53Ops()
  myLogger.log('doEverything Finished')
}

doEverything()
```

```
2018-11-29T07:47:47.158Z [DEBUG] testAws: testAws Starting
2018-11-29T07:47:47.160Z [DEBUG] testAws: About to create ec2 client
2018-11-29T07:47:47.189Z [DEBUG] testAws: ec2 client created
2018-11-29T07:47:47.189Z [DEBUG] testAws: About to create route53Domainsclient
2018-11-29T07:47:47.191Z [DEBUG] testAws: route53Domainsclient created
2018-11-29T07:47:47.192Z [DEBUG] testAws: doEverything Starting
2018-11-29T07:47:47.192Z [DEBUG] testAws: About to describeInstances
2018-11-29T07:47:47.493Z [DEBUG] testAws: [AWS ec2 200 0.299s 0 retries] describeInstances({})
2018-11-29T07:47:47.494Z [DEBUG] testAws: Successfully describeInstances: 
output: {
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Groups": [],
      "Instances": [
        {
          "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
          "ImageId": 
< I have removed a massive payload here as it has internal details >
2018-11-29T07:23:02.654Z [DEBUG] testAws: doInstanceOps complete
2018-11-29T07:23:02.654Z [DEBUG] testAws: About to listDomains
2018-11-29T07:23:03.272Z [DEBUG] testAws: [AWS route53domains 502 0.617s 3 retries] listDomains({})
2018-11-29T07:23:03.273Z [ERROR] testAws: Error listDomains: UnknownError: Bad Gateway
2018-11-29T07:23:03.273Z [ERROR] testAws: error in doRoute53Ops()
2018-11-29T07:23:03.273Z [DEBUG] testAws: doRoute53Ops complete
2018-11-29T07:23:03.273Z [DEBUG] testAws: doEverything Finished
```

My npm versions are:

```
C:\testApp\testApp-api>npm list aws-sdk
testApp-api@1.0.0 C:\testApp\testApp-api
+-- aws-sdk@2.364.0
`-- credstash@1.0.44
  `-- aws-sdk@2.2.35

C:\testApp\testApp-api>npm list proxy-agent
testApp-api@1.0.0 C:\testApp\testApp-api
`-- proxy-agent@3.0.3

C:\testApp\testApp-api>npm list logplease
testApp-api@1.0.0 C:\testApp\testApp-api
`-- logplease@1.2.15
```

I just tested with the http proxy config commented out from AWS.config, like this:

```
AWS.config.update({
  // httpOptions: { agent: proxy('http://myproxy.here:8080') },
  region: 'ap-southeast-2', // ec2 client needs this
  logger: myLogger
})
```

and I get this error instead:

```
2018-11-29T08:30:02.192Z [DEBUG] testAws: About to listDomains
2018-11-29T08:30:02.465Z [DEBUG] testAws: [AWS route53domains undefined 0.271s 3 retries] listDomains({})
2018-11-29T08:30:02.465Z [ERROR] testAws: Error listDomains: UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `route53domains.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `ap-southeast-2' region.
2018-11-29T08:30:02.465Z [ERROR] testAws: error in doRoute53Ops()
```

Comment: Seriously? Not even a nibble, this is node.js, aws and java script, I heard these were popular technologies, I can't be the only one using this :)

Answer (score 0):

On advice from AWS support, I changed the region from 'ap-southeast-2' to 'us-east-1', for the route53domains call, this resolved the issue.

For more information see this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html#default-region-provider-chain), it is for Java SDK but I am told it applies to the other SDK's too.

See "Amazon Route 53" on the [AWS Regions and Endpoints page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html), it shows this API service (route53domains) is only available in the single region 'us-east-1', so all calls to aws-sdk for route53domains globally need to go to the 'us-east-1' region.